# The `minted` package messes up with the `diagmat` module of `physics2`?

Tags: minted

I use the `minted` package to write code listings in my document and I use the `physics2` package for many of its useful modules. I tried to use the `diagmat` module to write diagonal matrices, and it seems that having the `minted` package loaded messes this up completely. Here's a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{physics2}

\usephysicsmodule{diagmat}

\begin{document}
\[ \pdiagmat{1, -1, 0} \]
\[ \pdiagmat[empty = {}]{a, b, c, d} \]
\end{document}
```

Compiling this messes the first 3x3 matrix and throws an error for the next 4x4 matrix:

[image]

Loading the `minted` package after `physics2` instead of before doesn't change anything. If I comment out the `minted` package, then everything works as expected:

[image]

I can't understand what's going on here. These two packages have completely different purposes and I can't figure out why they interfere with each other. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I compile with my up-to-date TeX Live 2023, I get the expected output. So I went to Overleaf and tried: the problem shows.

Adding `\listfiles` to both files (on my machine and Overleaf) and doing a `diff`, I get several instances of packages that have been updated since when Overleaf deployed TeX Live 2023.

```
9c9
<   minted.sty    2022/12/12 v2.7 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX
---
>   minted.sty    2023/12/18 v2.9 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX
12c12
<  ltxcmds.sty    2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
---
>  ltxcmds.sty    2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
14c14
<  fvextra.sty    2022/11/30 v1.5 fvextra - extensions and patches for fancyvrb
---
>  fvextra.sty    2023/11/28 v1.6.1 fvextra - extensions and patches for fancyvrb
16c16
< fancyvrb.sty    2023/01/19 4.5a verbatim text (tvz,hv)
---
> fancyvrb.sty    2023/11/06 4.5b verbatim text (tvz,hv)
20,21c20
<     calc.sty    2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
< shellesc.sty    2023/04/15 v1.0d unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
---
> shellesc.sty    2023/07/08 v1.0d unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
29,30c28,29
<  "output.w18"
<  xstring.sty    2023/01/14 v1.85 String manipulations (CT)
---
>   "diagm.w18"
>  xstring.sty    2023/08/22 v1.86 String manipulations (CT)
33,37c32,34
< physics2.sty    2023/04/02 v0.2.1 Tools for typesetting math for physics.
< phy-common.sty    2023/03/29 `common' module of `physics2.sty'
< phy-diagmat.sty    2023/01/25 `diagmat' module of `physics2.sty'
< phy-explsetup.sty    2023/01/25 `explsetup' module of `physics2.sty'
<   xcolor.sty    2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
---
> physics2.sty    2024/01/10 v1.0.1 Tools for typesetting math for physics.
> phy-diagmat.sty    2024/01/10 `diagmat' module of physics2
>   xcolor.sty    2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
41c38
< l3backend-pdftex.def    2023-04-19 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
---
> l3backend-pdftex.def    2024-01-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
```

I'm afraid you need an up-to-date TeX Live. However, the workaround proposed by Ulrike seems to work: no guarantee.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{physics2}
\usephysicsmodule{diagmat}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\robustify{\\}

\begin{document}
\[ \pdiagmat{1, -1, 0} \]
\[ \pdiagmat[empty = {}]{a, b, c, d} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The older physics2 falls over the redefinition of ``\\`` in lineno. ``\usepackage{etoolbox}\robustify\\`` could work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Seems to work, but maybe it's not enough.

Comment: @egreg This indeed works. If I understand your answer correctly, I could get rid of this workaround once Overleaf updates its TeX Live version, right?

Comment: @ShaiAvr Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: @egreg Thank you.